# What's the number in the cell marked by the question mark in the cell according to the pattern?

Tags: pattern

I came across the puzzle shown in the picture below. Please help me work out the number in the cell marked by the question mark. Thank you very much. This puzzle is from the exercise booklet for selective high school enrolment tests in Australia.
It's hard to discern the relationship between the numbers on the same row or in the same column. Or there may be other connections between numbers in defferent rows or columns. That would make things even more complicated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> 10

Reason:

> Each column adds up to 11

Comment: Thank you, Prim3numbah. That's the pattern. Dumb me. Didn't think about the problem in a simpler way. But in many cases, simplicity is beauty.

Comment: Yes that's often the case.No prob :)